# exposing an object using manager/proxy in a different process

Tags: python, multiprocessing

So I have this object that is available in a different process. How can I expose this object using an alias in my current process so that whenever I call a method on the alias (proxy), it will be pickled and called on the referent object and raise any exceptions if there is.

I also like the data to be sent over a pipe, not sockets.

The examples I see on multiprocessing page in python does not address this scenario. or at least doesn't directly.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using BaseManager.start() to spawn a new process for the manager. I also used a customized proxy by subclassing BaseProxy and registered the proxy with the manager.

I still don't know how to create a pipe into the spawned process, but that wasn't the main problem anyways.